# Curvature and torsion

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, curvature

Show that the torsion for the space curve $x=2t+\frac{1}{t}-1 ,y= \frac{t^2}{t-1}, z=t+2$ is zero.

Actually when I apply the direct formula for curvature and torsion the problem becomes very complicated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Equivalently you can show that binormal vector of the curve is constant.

Answer (score 0):

This question is **wrong**.

The torsion is *NOT* zero.

Remark:
Assume $t\neq 0,1$.

The z-coordinate of $r^{'}(t)$ is 1.

So the z-coordinate of $r^{''}(t)$ and $r^{'''}(t)$ is 0.

Then to compute $(r^{'}\times r^{''})\cdot r^{'''}$,

$(r^{'}\times r^{''})\cdot r^{'''}=\frac{-12}{t^4 \cdot (t-1)^4} \neq 0$

Checking using this online calculator:

https://www.emathhelp.net/en/calculators/calculus-3/torsion-calculator/?rx=2t+%2B1%2Ft-1&ry=%28t%5E2%29%2F%28t-1%29&rz=t%2B2&t=